# For LTR on specific layout/resource even if running in RTL

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to support RTL.
I've added `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `Application` element in the manifest and it looks great.
However, there are a few layouts that should stay the same for both LTR/RTL. I know I can copy the layout file to a `layout-ldrtl` directory but I prefer to have only 1 copy of the resource if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force LTR for a layout, you can add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to the layout XML tag like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    ...>
```